# Prove that the equation $5 \sqrt{\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{19}{4}$ has exactly one solution

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

Prove that the equation $5 \sqrt{\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{19}{4}$  has a exactly one solution in the interval $(0,1)$. Find this solution with accuracy up to $0.25$.
I thought about it, and still cannot find where to start.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is this $$5\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{19}{4}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$5\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{19}{4}\tag1$$

Divide both sides by $5$:

$$\sqrt{\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{19}{20}\tag2$$

Raise both sides to the power of two:

$$\sin\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{361}{400}\tag3$$

Take the inverse sine of both sides:

$$x^2+\frac{1}{2}=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{361}{400}\right)+2\pi\text{k}_1\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x^2+\frac{1}{2}=\arcsin\left(\frac{361}{400}\right)+2\pi\text{k}_2\tag4$$

Where $\text{k}_1\space\wedge\space\text{k}_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

Subtract $\frac{1}{2}$ from both sides and take the square root of both sides:

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\pi-\frac{1}{2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{361}{400}\right)+2\pi\text{k}_1}\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x=\pm\sqrt{\arcsin\left(\frac{361}{400}\right)-\frac{1}{2}+2\pi\text{k}_2}\tag5$$

Now, a few cases:

1. $\text{k}_1=\text{k}_2=0$:
   $$x\approx\pm1.23128\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x\approx\pm0.79091\tag6$$
2. $\text{k}_1=\text{k}_2=1$:
   $$x\approx\pm2.79271\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x\approx\pm2.628445\tag7$$